# Pine script - Count bar from condition

Tags: pine-script, trading

How can I have a bar number from when a condition is true?
barssince give me alway value 0

I need for create a series of trailing stop loss.

Here it is my code

```
    SMA16=sma(close,16)
SMA50=sma(close,50)
plot(SMA16,color=color.red)
plot(SMA50,color=color.blue)



longcondition=crossover(SMA16,SMA50)

count = barssince(longcondition)

SL=valuewhen(longcondition,close,0)*0.5
TSL = SL + highest(high,count)-valuewhen(longcondition,close,0)

plot(TSL,color=color.navy)    
plot(SL,color=color.black)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with `highest()` is that at first bar (`bar_index` = 0) you passing to it length = 0. You need to handle this:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", max_bars_back = 300)

SMA16=sma(close,16)
SMA50=sma(close,50)
plot(SMA16,color=color.red)
plot(SMA50,color=color.blue)

longcondition=crossover(SMA16,SMA50)

var int bar = 0
var int count = 0

if longcondition
    bar := bar_index
count := bar_index - bar + 1

SL=valuewhen(longcondition,close,0)*0.5
TSL = SL + highest(high,count)-valuewhen(longcondition,close,0)

plot(TSL,color=color.navy)    
plot(SL,color=color.black)
```

With `barssince()`

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", max_bars_back = 300)

SMA16=sma(close,16)
SMA50=sma(close,50)
plot(SMA16,color=color.red)
plot(SMA50,color=color.blue)
longcondition=crossover(SMA16,SMA50)

b = barssince(longcondition)
count = na(b)? 1 : b

SL=valuewhen(longcondition,close,0)*0.5
TSL = SL + highest(high,count+1)-valuewhen(longcondition,close,0)

plot(TSL,color=color.navy)    
plot(SL,color=color.black)
```

Comment: Thanks but, I have different error now: Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series. Try using max_bars_back

Comment: updated example